# JSON elements don't load into the DOM javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage, e-commerce

Hello guys I get an error every time I try to load the Elements:

> undefined:1 GET
> file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/JSLearn/myC3/myC3/undefined
> net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Image (async) addEspresso @ shopJS.js:37
> onclick @ coffeeShop.html:54

**Here's my js code:**

```
let pList = document.getElementById("productList")
 const addEspresso = () => {
  let Espresso, esp, eObj;
  Espresso = {
    name: "Espresso",
    type: "strong",
    imgSrc: "images/c7.png"
  };

  // get the existing localStorage first
  esp = localStorage.getItem("Espresso");
  if (!esp) eObj = [];
  else eObj = JSON.parse(esp);
  // it should be an array or create one if empty
  eObj.push(Espresso)
  // add eObj to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem("Espresso", JSON.stringify(eObj));

  let espresso = "";
  eObj.forEach((item,i) => {  // item is the item, i is the index
  espresso += `
         <div class="productDiv" data-index="${i}">
         <p>${eObj.name}</p> 
         <p>${eObj.type}</p>
         <img src="${eObj.imgSrc}">
         <button class="btn-remove">REMOVE</button>
         </div>
        `
   });
  document.getElementById("productList").innerHTML = espresso
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('btn-remove')) {
    // before removing, lets get the data-index value so we can remove the right one from localStorage
    let index = e.target.closest('.productDiv').dataset.index
    e.target.closest('.productDiv').remove();
    // adjust localStorage
    let eObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Espresso"));
    eObj.splice(index,1)
    localStorage.setItem("Espresso", JSON.stringify(eObj));
  }
})
```

**My html code:**

```
<div class="iList">
     <div class="cList">
       <img src="images/c7.png"class = "Espresso">
       <h1 class="Type">Espresso</h1>
       <button id="espAdd"onclick="addEspresso()">Add Espresso</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Localstorage items are added and removed,but DOM does not want to load because of error I've mentioned before,I think that the problem is in data.index.Any help will be appreciated!**

Comment: There is no element with id "productList". Kindly provide us with the code to reproduce your error

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add it,it is defined:let pList = document.getElementById("productList"),that is not the problem because the elements show up in the DOM as "undefined" "undefined" and an unloaded image icon